# I am trying to use CSS style display: inline-block; with 2 <div> but they are not displaying right next to each other

Tags: html, css

Below is my HTML and CSS snippet.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
       .box1{
           background-color: seagreen;
           display: inline-block;
           margin: 5px;
           padding: 4px;
           width: 433px;
           height: 233px;
           border: 2px solid black;
           
       }
       .box2{
            background-color: sienna;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 433px;
            height: 233px;
            border: 2px solid black;
       }
    </style>
    <title>Asspend21</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, molestiae cupiditate voluptatibus recusandae quibusdam ad, iure ratione consequuntur magni doloremque vel nemo eius magnam placeat saepe aspernatur ex? Molestias itaque ex voluptatem sit, minima incidunt nulla facilis dolores accusant!</div>
    <div class="box2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem harum laudantium sapiente quos eos nam officiis et laborum fuga minus dolore vitae error quia corporis amet, labore temporibus ex soluta quod laboriosam beatae optio maiores, eum illum. Voluptatibus, hic aperiam eaque quam obcaecati nemo minima tempore dolorem similique impedit, harum magni quis ducimus veritatis id saepe</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's coming like this.
[image: Image01]

Even after removing padding and margin, It's still displaying the same. What is required to resolve the issue ?
What is the issue here?

Comment: Have you tried setting the font size to zero in the wrapping container?

Comment: Haven't touched fonts size.

Comment: The only change you need is to add `vertical-align: top` in the first `.box1` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest your divs in a `wrapper` and use flex-box to align your two divs. See the changes I made to your HTML and CSS in the below snippet. Using `flex-box` instead of margins or float's will give you much more control over the positioning of your divs.

```css
*{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
       .box1{
           background-color: seagreen;
           display: inline-block;
           margin: 5px;
           padding: 5px;
           width: 433px;
           height: 233px;
           border: 2px solid black;
           
       }
       .box2{
            background-color: sienna;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 433px;
            height: 233px;
            border: 2px solid black;
       }
       
       .wrapper {
         display: flex;
       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Asspend21</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, molestiae cupiditate voluptatibus recusandae quibusdam ad, iure ratione consequuntur magni doloremque vel nemo eius magnam placeat saepe aspernatur ex? Molestias itaque ex voluptatem sit, minima incidunt nulla facilis dolores accusant!</div>
    <div class="box2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem harum laudantium sapiente quos eos nam officiis et laborum fuga minus dolore vitae error quia corporis amet, labore temporibus ex soluta quod laboriosam beatae optio maiores, eum illum. Voluptatibus, hic aperiam eaque quam obcaecati nemo minima tempore dolorem similique impedit, harum magni quis ducimus veritatis id saepe</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SubhamSood No problem. I recommend flex-box because it will give you much more control on easily changing the positioning of the nested elements when expanding your design.

Answer (score 2):

Add `float: left` to `.box1` to align them again :).

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you for the help.
Can you please tell me what was the root cause for this?

Answer (score 2):

The root problem is that your div has the wrong vertical alignment. Just set `vertical-align: top;` to the divs that need to be positioned and the problem is solved.

You can find a good explanation here: [H2 inside div inline-block weird offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113296/h2-inside-div-inline-block-weird-offset)

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
       .box1{
           background-color: seagreen;
           display: inline-block;
           margin: 5px;
           padding: 4px;
           width: 433px;
           height: 233px;
           border: 2px solid black;
           vertical-align: top;
       }
       .box2{
            background-color: sienna;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 433px;
            height: 233px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            vertical-align: top;
       }
    </style>
    <title>Asspend21</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi, molestiae cupiditate voluptatibus recusandae quibusdam ad, iure ratione consequuntur magni doloremque vel nemo eius magnam placeat saepe aspernatur ex? Molestias itaque ex voluptatem sit, minima incidunt nulla facilis dolores accusant!</div>
    <div class="box2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem harum laudantium sapiente quos eos nam officiis et laborum fuga minus dolore vitae error quia corporis amet, labore temporibus ex soluta quod laboriosam beatae optio maiores, eum illum. Voluptatibus, hic aperiam eaque quam obcaecati nemo minima tempore dolorem similique impedit, harum magni quis ducimus veritatis id saepe</div>
</body>
</html>
```